# Connecting to Oracle 11gR2 XE on Ubuntu 13 server via PHP

Tags: php, oracle, ipv6, ubuntu-server

I am trying to connect to Oracle 11gR2 Xe on Ubuntu 13 server from another computer in the network, via PHP.
I am using installs and examples followed from  [oci_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) like here:

```
<?php
query_cities();
function query_cities() {
if {
$c = oci_connect("hr", "hr", "localhost:1521/XE");
;
} else {
echo "No connection"; } 
?>
```

or another example like:

```
$c = oci_connect("hr", "hr", "192.168.1.33:1521/XE");
```

I have already enabled the remote connection in DB via SqlPlus

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
```

and i have unlocked the user HR

```
SQL> ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

but I can only find some connection via IPv6 on the network from SQL Developer, like netstat:

tcp6  0  0 192.168.1.33:1521  192.168.1.2:57563  ESTABLISHED 14843/oracleXE

tcp6  0  0 192.168.1.33:1521  192.168.1.2:59314  ESTABLISHED 15665/oracleXE

not from my browser and they are not on tcp IPv4. The browser window remain white .. no reaction, unresponsive and no error message.
Should this be due to the TNSLR IP is active only on IPv6 or non of the oci_connect formulas are good enough or I am missing some other else?

I would appreciate any help on this issues

Comment: Don't test in a browser window. By default, all errors will result in a blank page. You have to back to the error logs to see the error. That is what you are seeing - the error is in the error logs. I expect it to be that you haven't installed or enabled oci8 in PHP.

Comment: I'm confused to see tcp6 connections with IPv4 addresses from netstat. When does this happen?

Comment: About IPv6 the interface is: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:6f:65:d8:7d:b7
          inet addr:192.168.1.33  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.25
          inet6 addr: fe80::1e6f:65ff:fed8:7db7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1096637 errors:0 dropped:259 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70353 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:172696685 (172.6 MB)  TX bytes:14938460 (14.9 MB)
and the ports are like this

Comment: netstat -tupan
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
tcp   0 0 127.0.0.1:3306  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  904/mysqld
tcp   0 0 127.0.0.1:55948 127.0.1.1:1521 ESTABLISHED 9152/xe_pmon_X
tcp6  0 0 127.0.0.1:8005 :::* LISTEN  1260/java
tcp6  0 0 :::8009 :::* LISTEN 1260/java
tcp6  0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 8947/tnslsnr
tcp6  0 0 :::80   :::* LISTEN 7900/apache2
tcp6  0 0 :::1521 :::* LISTEN 8947/tnslsnr
tcp6  0 0 :::8081 :::* LISTEN 1260/java
tcp6  0 0 :::22   :::* LISTEN 884/sshd
tcp6  0 0 :::443  :::* LISTEN 7900/apache2
tcp6  0 0 127.0.1.1:1521 127.0.0.1:55948  ESTABLISHED 8947/tnslsnr

Comment: I get the point about the logs, they look the error like this:
[error] [client 192.168.1.10] PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories

Answer (score 0):

Alright, on the basis of received advice to seek the error in logs, I've found the message "*There is something wrong with your system - please check that ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set and point to the right directories*" and I decided to go through the sophisticated process of installing the Oracle InstantClient and reinstall OCI8 package, after the model from [st-curriculum.oracle](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/opensrclang/phphol2010_db/php_db.htm) - with very small modifications, as follows:

1. Oracle 11g R2 XE database and Apache2 / PHP server have been apriori installed on Ubuntu 13.10 server and system prepared (with  prereqiuzite, swap file, kernel parameters, memory leak error recover, libraries and chkconfig emulator), as described in many posts.
2. I stopped apache2 server

   ```
    service apache2 stop
   ```

   and started DRCP connection pooling as in st-curriculum.oracle.com
3. I created a user named PHPHOL (and alternate install Oracle's sample HR schema, if not already done at oracle install)
4. Next I downloaded the Basic and the SDK Instant Client packages from OTN:  oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html and unzipped the packages in $ORACLE_HOME, (/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
5. Then I downloaded the OCI8 packeage from pecl.php.net/package/oci8 and installed in /opt/oci8 as instantclient

   ```
   phpise
   ./configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/instantclient_11_2
   make / make install
   ```
6. I set the oracle environment path as in [oracle technote](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html)

   ```
   export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe        
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/instantclient_11_2
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oci8/modules

   nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
   ```

   and insert: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/instantclient_11_2

   ```
   nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oci8.conf
   ```

   and insert: /opt/oci8/modules

   ```
   nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/shared.conf
   ```

   and insert the installed shared extensions location: /usr/lib/php5/20121212

   ```
   ldconfig
   ```
7. Next I edited the configuration file php.ini to add: extension=oci8.so, set the date.timezone directive and added also the OCI8 1.4 extension class: oci8.connection_class = MYPHPAPP (for the st-curriculum.oracle.com examples, see link above)
8. I made the link: $ORACLE_HOME/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so.11.1. to points to $ORACLE_HOME/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.so
9. Restart Oracle database and Apache services on Ubuntu 13.10 server

   ```
   /etc/init.d/oracle-xe force-reload
   service apache2 start
   ```
10. I verified in phpinfo() the oci8 was enabled, and I made the connect.php file like:

    ```
    $conn = oci_connect("hr", "hr", "localhost/xe");
    ```

or like the one from st-curriculum.oracle.com example.

From another computer on the same network I connected through a browser to oracle database on Ubuntu server and I've got

Connected to Oracle!

I hope this help